# Firebase Database Rules - Is this necessary?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Are Firebase's database rules absolutely necessary? In my app, I've made it so a user can only login to their own account if they know the password. And then every time I access firestore, I only pull data that belong to that user's id. So, why are firebase's rules necessary? Is it just a secondary measure? Asking because I'm also running into a lot of issues with testing firebase rules.

Example.

I have the below rules and they don't work, but without posting my entire code file here (which I don't feel comfortable doing), no one can really help me figure out why it's not working. The code below in theory should work but doesnt.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    match /routines/{routine} {
        allow read, write, update: if request.auth != null && resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to say if your rules work without also showing the code that performs the query that doesn't work.  The rules mean nothing if not paired with queries.  And yes, rules are necessary for direct app access unless you want anyone on the internet to read and write all data in your database.  Unless that's what you want.

Comment: Also, if you're going to require authentication on your rules, you'll have to make sure that a user is signed in.  Your code sample should help us know for sure that this is the case.

Comment: What do you mean when you say they don't work? Do you mean a user who is not logged in can read, write from the users collection? Elaborate on what isn't working.

Comment: When I say it doesn't work, I mean that I can't read or write any data. I think the issue here is that I've built out an entire relatively complicated app where I'm running many many firestore queries, so I don't even know where to begin in terms of sharing code or debugging or learning this :( Any recommendation on how I could start?

Comment: You need to add the code related to the queries you mentioned that are not working. This way, it will be possible to understand why they are not returning and if it's indeed, related to your security rules.